# Is capacitor noise due to observed step charging?

Tags: capacitor, noise

According to Tom Bearden and Per Wallander the capacitor step charges and step discharges. Se for example [Per Wallander, My way of understanding
electromagnetism, section 2.3 page 13](http://perant.se/Radiation/My%20way%202017.pdf):

> What we see on the oscilloscope is a staircase produced by the signal which is reflected
> at the far end, total reflection, but also being rereflected at the generator end
> according to the reflection coefficient.

Wallander has a [video showing the effect on oscilloscope with a cable capacitor](https://youtu.be/7zuNaLjSk7E?t=164).

This stepwise measured behavior differs from the smooth exponential curve that we have been taught that capacitor charge changes follow. I wonder how this difference is perceived?

The design practice to parallel connect capacitors of different sizes to minimize noise also support the idea that capacitor noise is due to stepwise voltage change.

Is this effect included in what is called capacitor noise?

Since people misunderstand this question I repeat that it is the **observed** step wise voltage change in the capacitor I am referring to.

Comment: what noise piezo-ceramic? or dC/dV noise? or current pulse ripple? ... has nothing to do with article

Comment: I'm not reading that document. Sorry. The usual meaning of capacitor noise is \$\frac{k\,T}{C}\$. Is that what the document is discussing? Because if so it's just due to an equipartition law of energy (50/50 split between kinetic and potential.)

Comment: HAven't read the article: You can apply step CHARGING oulses to a capacitor BUT a capacitor NEVER step charges. Vcap CANNOT change instantaneously. You can apply a constant current and have the voltage change as a linear ramp , or a resistively fed voltage and have it exponentially change voltage. | You can apply a stiff voltage source via a very low impedance path and you will get a rapid transition and large currents - but the R & L components of the charge path and the sourve and the capacitor will cause the voltage change to 'obey the laws of Physics'.

Comment: Have now looked at the most relevant parts of the article. The steps on page 28 and 29 are due to use of a pulse generator and his descriptions of what happens are essentially consistent with what I said in my necessarily simplified answer and comment. Several apply but eg "... but the R & L components of the charge path and the source and the capacitor will cause the voltage change to 'obey the laws of Physics'...." | Note that while on p28-29 he may seem to be sayong somethingh different to received truth is happening, he's not. On p30b he says " ... Connect the capacitors. ...

Comment: ... The power rush into the next capacitor and the
currents are no longer equal. We get ohmic losses in the capacitor plates.
The maximum power one source can deliver in the real ohmic world is
half of its energy. That holds even here." <- all his WORDS. || - That's essentially no different than applying a pulse generator pulse - which COULD be sourced from a capacitor with partial discharge. You will get resistive losses and half energy loss during capacitor charging. ...

Comment: ... Ideal caps and no R & L just get you "ideal" infinite currents with losses in the I^2R  of infinite current and zero R. (Nature sorts out the multiple infinities that never occur in reality to produce the same results as ever).

Comment: Please check the video I just included in the question. The effect is easily observed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment - highly (probably) relevant.
While not directly answering the question proper the key point raised (a capacitor CANNOT step charge) must be understood.

You can apply step CHARGING pulses to a capacitor
BUT a capacitor NEVER step charges.
Vcap CANNOT change instantaneously.
(The annoying laws of Physics include this fact in the definition of what defines a capacitor).

You can apply a constant current and have the voltage change as a linear ramp ,
or a resistively fed voltage and have it exponentially change voltage.

Wishing to tempt Murphy,
you can apply a stiff voltage source
via a very low impedance path
and you will get a rapid transition and large currents - but the R & L components of the charge path and the source and the capacitor will cause the voltage change to 'obey the laws of Physics'.

---

> You are not answering the question.
>   This is not about how an idealised dogma of capacitors work.
>   It is about how real capacitors behave.

I AM answering the question.
A real capacitor is an ideal capacitor with added ideal series resistance, ideal lead inductance, ideal leakage resistance and more scattered idealities, in many cases probably distributed rather than lump.

While the non-idealised-dogma of capacitors you buy "gets you through" often enough, you cannot avoid the laws of physics which control basic behaviour.
The ideal capacitor [tm] lurking in the non-idealised component CANNOT be forced to step change in voltage. It can SEEM to due to the ESR allowing you to apply V=IR, and the inductance to allow step voltage BUT NOT step current. And ... .

Capacitor paralleling to reduce noise from step charge can be explained several ways (All models are wrong, some models are useful) including that each capacitor has ESR and ESL and a resonant frequency and transfer function, and that a step voltage is able to be modeled as an infinite series of sine waves of decreasing amplitude (F0 + 1/3 F3 + 1/5 F5 + ...) so your multiple-capacitor-formed band pass (to ground) filters provide a wider band width than a single cap.
The dogma of real life is complex.

Comment: You are not answering the question. This is not about how an idealised dogma of capacitors work. It is about how real capacitors behave.

Comment: @DavidJonsson I AM answering the question. A real capacitor is an ideal capacitor with added ideal series resistance, ideal lead inductance, ideal leakage resistance and more scattered idealities, in many cases probably distributed rather than lump. While the non-idealised-dogma of capacitors you buy "gets you through" often enough, you cannot avoid the laws of physics which control basic behaviour. The ideal capacitor [tm] lurking in the non-idealised component CANNOT be forced to step change in voltage. It can SEEM to due to the ESR allowing you to apply V=IR, and the inductance to allow ..

Comment: ... step voltage BUT NOT step current. And ... . || Capacitor paralleling to reduce noise from step charge can be explained several ways (All models are wrong, some models are useful) including that each capacitor has ESR and ESL and a resonant frequency and transfer function, and that a step voltage is able to be modelled as an infinite series of sine waves of decreasing amplitude (F0 + 1/3 F3 + 1/5 F5 + ...) so your multiple capacitor formed band pass (to ground) filters provide a wider band width than a single cap. || The dogma of real life is complex.

Answer (score 0):

Page 13 of the referenced article...

The illustration is simply the waveform at the transmitter (generator) when the source impedance of the generator(50 ohms) is less than the characteristic impedance of the transmission line (300 ohms) and the transmission line is un-terminated at the far end.

I think the author is just showing a pathological, ideal case.  In the real world, the individual steps would all have some rounding on their edges depending on the drive strength of the generator.

And NO, this is not what I would call capacitor noise.